# I'm replacing an old 3-wire motion sensor with a new sensor that has 4 wires. How do I install this?

Tags: electrical, wiring, motion-sensor

I'm replacing an old 3-wire motion sensor (cracked housing) with a new Leviton [PS100-70W motion sensor](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/PS110-PS200_IST.pdf). This new sensor has 4 wires (1 black, 1 white, 2 blue). How do I install this properly? I understand the black and white wires, but don't know what to do with the blue wires.

Comment: Can you post the installation instructions for your new sensor please?

Comment: Are you sure the second blue is blue, and not **green**?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the document you linked one blue wire connects to live and the other to the live terminal of he lamps.